# FFXI: What is some RDM eq worth buying?

Tags: final-fantasy-11

The game has changed drastically in the past years and nowadays, eq is more often obtained via Abyssea/etc and not the AH.

I'm a 99 RDM but lacking on gear; I happen to have about 2 million Gil that I am looking to spend on what I need most: equipment.

What is truly worth buying? There is a lot I could buy, but a lot of it isn't worth it as the time spent obtaining it is not that much.

(Carbuncle server)

Comment: What server are you on?  The economies vary dramatically.

Comment: Good point. Carbuncle server.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized to a point in time.  Any answers provided will become invalid as the economy shifts.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to buy a [Iridal Staff](http://www.ffxiah.com/item/18632/iridal-staff) and then a [Chatoyant Staff](http://www.ffxiah.com/item/18633/chatoyant-staff) when you get some more money.  These are a must have while you work on the required Magian Staves.

From there you are going to want a decent MND set, enfeebling set, and healing set.  RDM only really shines in Delve right now so you are going to want to focus on landing enfeebles and then supporting your party with cures.

As you said a lot of the gear you need will come from Abyssea.  Don't forget a few AF2 pieces are great as well.